# Kali 2.0 multiple issues

Tags: linux, freeze, kali-linux

I've been experiencing a lot, and I mean, A LOT of issues with Kali 2.0. Have researched the Kali forums, the Internet and even people around that have experience in Linux (especially BackTrack 5). The issues are:

1. commonly asked one: the shutdown/restart/reboot freezes.
2. the more than one freeze: the OS completely freezes upon connecting another display or monitor via VGA and HDMI.
3. the repositories, the "E: repository not found error", that prevents the solving of the other two.

How can these issues be resolved?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Nobody here lives inside your head; we can't read your mind.  Rather than saying "commonly asked one" and "the '...' problem", please actually describe your problems.  And rather than saying "nothing that I found online seems to work", tell us what you tried and what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Man and thank you. the repos issue is solved, one tiny source missing (***deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib***). Had to dig really deep in the kali forum to discover it. As for the other two it is as described. I think I've found a solution for number 1 (***http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/08/04/howto-fix-linux-hangfreeze-during-reboots-and-restarts/***). After testing it I'll give feedback. Number two, I haven't found nothing more yet, the issue is this: I have a display (samsung Syncmaster 710v) that I use for multi-display (obvious); when I connect the display (through VGA) to the computer it just freezes and the display has no input. Could be a GPU, graphics card drivers issue and I've found some info online about it, did not work (possibly because of 3). Going to try all this tomorrow and lets see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for trying to close the loop on your question.  Unlike a forum, which uses a thread of sequential posts, this ia a Q&A site.  It relies on questions being questions and answers being solutions to them.  Your answer is a mixed bag that will confuse people.  Let me suggest something that will help get you answers.  Limit the answer to the portion you solved and how you did that, which will be useful to others.  The information that helps to clarify and update your question, add that to the question (tack it on or revise the question to merge the information).